# UIscrollview scroll affects other scrollviews

Tags: objective-c, ios

Im a very begginer to iOS, i'm certainly struggling with `UIScrollview`. In my app i have an multiple `UIscrollviews` each positioned one below one, here when i scroll any `scrollview` every `scrollview` has to be **SCROLLED** in the same **DIRECTION**. I'm adding `UIScrollviews` programatically in a `UIView` class and then adding them as a `SUBVIEWS` to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set up delegates for your scroll views and implement `scrollViewDidScroll`: to update the content offset of the other scroll views.

Answer (score 0):

```
in Scroll view delegate method check the condition 

-(void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
if(scrollView != self.yourCurrentScrollView)
{
    return;
}
else{
 // do something    
}
}

- (void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate
{
   if(scrollView != self.yourCurrentScrollView)
{
    return;
}
else{
// do something
}
}
```